# Simplest way to check if user is entering duplicates in a List of objects?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a system where a customer can register and the credentials get saved in a .bat file(Schoolwork). One thing that needs to be done is that the username that the user enters has to be unique and cannot already exist. However I can't get this to work, it will keep looping and prompting the user for a username even tho the username doesn't exist. There are other objects such as Name and Surname that need to be added to the List and their values entered by the user but those don't have to be unique.

Some things to note are that the List is created in another class called 'Database.cs' and that 'Customer' class inherits from 'Person'. If you want me to show more of the code if this isn't enough please tell me. Thanks.

In Database.cs

```
class Database

{

    public List<Customer> Customer { get; set; }

}
```

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

In program.cs

```
static void AddCustomer(){

        Customer customer = new Customer();

        Database db = new Database();

        bool alreadyexists = db.Customer.Any(item => item.Username == customer.Username);

        do
        {
            if (alreadyexists == false)
            {
                Console.Write("Username: ");
                customer.Username = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Username already exists");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            BusinessManager.Instance.AddCustomer(customer);
            BusinessManager.Instance.SaveChanges();
        } while (!alreadyexists);
```

}

This will then be passed on to another class called 'BusinessManager.cs'

```
public void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        DataManager.Instance.AddCustomer(customer);
    }
```

This will then be passed to another method in a class called 'DataManager.cs'

```
class DataManager
{
    static DataManager singleton;
    static Database db = null;

    public static DataManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (singleton == null)
                singleton = new DataManager();
            return singleton;
        }
    }

    public DataManager()
    {
        db = new Database();
    }

public void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        db.Customer.Add(customer);
    }
```

Comment: Two things - you need to check if the username exists *after* you add it to `customer`, and secondly the linq statement doesn't need to refer to the `ID` value at all - just `username`, since that's all you're bothered about.

Comment: Are you looking to prevent duplicates (check to see if an entry exists before an insert), or looking to find duplicates in an existing list?  Your question title sounds like the latter, but your description sounds like the former.

Comment: Hey guys sorry for not clarifying this I will edit it. The username doesn't exist, I will type in a new username but it will still prompt me to enter the username. And I forgot to remove the reference to ID.

Comment: If you want to find duplicates in a List<T> you can group by name and ID and then select the groupings with more than 2 items, eg `Customers.GroupBy(c=>new {c.UserName,c.Id}).Where(grp=>grp.Length>1).Select(grp=>handleTheDuplicates)`

Comment: That's because you set `alreadyExists` to false and *then* start the loop with the input.

Comment: @Lumstr in this case you aren't looking for duplicates, you are checking whether something exists or not. `Any` should work but you can improve performance if you create a dictionary out of that list with the username as key

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you've misunderstood the question - your suggestions will definitely confuse the issue

Comment: @Archer the title says `check for duplicates`, not existence. But yes, I didn't notice that the loop is broken

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think it's just a badly worded title.  It threw me at first and then I realised when they're trying to do.

Comment: I changed the tittle, hopefully it clarifies my issue, I still can't get this to work unfortunately..

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding the question correctly then this will do what you need...

```
static void AddCustomer()
{
    Database db = new Database();

    // declare the variable - populate its value later
    bool alreadyExists;

    do
    {
        Console.Write("Username: ");
        var username = Console.ReadLine();

        // check the value the user just entered
        alreadyExists = db.Customer.Any(item => item.Username == username);

        if (alreadyExists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Username already exists");
        }
    }
    // if alreadyExists is true, repeat
    while (alreadyexists);

    // now that we have a username that is not in the list, 
    // add the new customer, using the username variable
    var customer = new Customer
    {
        Username = username
    };

    BusinessManager.Instance.AddCustomer(customer);
    BusinessManager.Instance.SaveChanges();
}
```

You mostly had it but you were checking that the username already exists *before* it was entered, and you were also continuing the do/while loop until the user entered a duplicate.

Once you've entered a new username that isn't in the list, it creates a new Customer object and uses the `BusinessManager` class to add and save it.

Comment: I tried this but even after I enter the same Username it will still add the object to the list with the already existing value. I don't know at this point why it shouldn't work...

Comment: The while statement here should be !alreadyexists not alreadyexists.

Comment: @SamuelWarren No it should not - you only want to loop if the username you entered already exists.  If not then exit the loop.

Comment: @Lumster The code you posted isn't adding anything to a list.  There must be something wrong outside the code I've posted here as it's pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Ah ok. I was backwards.

Comment: The objects are being added to the list, I can confirm this because there is another method that lists every customer, and every customer added to the list is shown, including ones with the same Username. Is any clearer way I can show you the project without posting the entire code here?

Comment: What I mean is that there is nothing in the code that you posted, or in the code that I've posted, that adds anything to any list.  It's literally just a loop that stops you adding something that is already in the list.  If you're adding things elsewhere then that's a different matter.  Can you explain where, in the code you've posted, you add anything to a list?

Comment: I will edit the post and show you how I'm adding the Objects to the List

Comment: I added additional code to further show what the project is doing. Sorry for the frustrations...

Comment: Yeah, you were adding the customer inside the loop where you're trying to get a unique username, so it would just keep adding and adding them.  I've modified my code now so it waits till you enter a new username and *then* creates and adds the customer object to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your `alreadyexists` variable will only execute once, when this line is reached:

```
bool alreadyexists = db.Customer.Any(item => item.Username == customer.Username && item.ID == customer.ID);
```

And then when you check it in the while loop iterations, the value is still the same as when it first executed. To re-execute that query in each iteration, you can definitely `alreadyexists` as a delegate:

```
Func<bool> alreadyexists = () => db.Customer.Any(item => item.Username == customer.Username && item.ID == customer.ID);
```

Comment: Seems a little convoluted... why not just `while (db.Customer.Any(item => item.Username == customer.Username))`?

Comment: Good points. I suppose the trade-off there is that you lose the named variable that allows the reader to quickly understand the intention of the query. Regardless, I think those are just details and the solution still applies.